# Как записать вывод команды 'pip freeze' в файл с помошью python?

Tags: pip

```
import os
f = open file('pip')
from i in os.sistem('pip freeze'):
f.write(i)
f.close()
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Откуда такие причудливые конструкции?

Comment: Я рекомендую сперва ознакомиться с синтаксисом python. В вашем примере код похож на питон, но не является синтаксически правильным. К примеру для открытия файла нужно `f = open('pip')`. И ещё целый ряд неправильных конструкций.

Comment: да синтаксически чуть ошибся ,сори но все ровно не удается записать в файл(